# Getting some strange error in android studio - gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

A problem occurred evaluating project ':Wallpaperapp'.

> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileTree) values: [directory 'libs']
>   Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)

ps- it was working properly,i reinstalled sdk in diff path.after that its not working.Please any one help me?

Comment: Can you please include your build.gradle file in the question ? Also make sure the sdk path is properly configured in Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure any lines in your build.gradle that have "compile" and "libs" in that line have the right syntax for the Gradle version you are using.